# for loop in transact sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, for-loop

I have a table that contains some data that needs to be updated. Let's assume that the table structure is

```
(Code, Col1, Col2, Col3)
```

I need to run an update on specific rows that have the Code value (let's say the values are `(1,3,4,5,9,6,30,25,87,100)`).

The Col3 value is Col1+Col2 and the Col1 values are `(1001,1025,400,25,963,13,432,25,87,100)`.

I created the following SQL Query:

```
Declare @Col1 float
Declare @Code nvarchar

set @Col1 = 1001
set @Code = 1

update MyTable set
    Col1 = @Col1,
    Col3 = @Col1 + Col2
where Code = @Code
```

So, instead copying all this code after the Declare lines and manually assigning values, is it possible to create two arrays, one for Col1 values other for Code values and iterate through the Code and updating it dynamically?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you intent to do, but I'm fairly sure you don't need a loop. Remember sql is set-based, not row-based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually iteration over rows of data using loops or cursors considered as bad practice in SQL since it is much slower in most cases.

In your particular case there is no need to iterate over some "arrays" to perform your desired update.

Instead you can create temporary table like this:

```
create table #temp_table (Col1 float, Code nvarchar(10))
```

fill it with your data like:

```
insert into #temp_table (Col1, Code)
select 1001, '1'
union all
select 1025, '3'
... and so on
```

and then perform your update:

```
update MyTable set
    Col1 = T1.Col1,
    Col3 = T1.Col1 + Col2
from MyTable as T
    inner join #temp_table as T1 on T.Code = T1.Code
```

Comment: Upvoted this over the CTE, as the temp-table provides more long-term flexibility

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for this, you can just create a Cte (or temp table) with the values you want to update, and `JOIN` to it in an `UPDATE` statement:

```
;With ToUpdate (Code, Col1) As
(
    Select  1, 1001     Union All
    Select  3, 1025     Union All
    Select  4, 400      Union All
    Select  5, 25       Union All
    Select  9, 963      Union All
    Select  6, 13       Union All
    Select  30, 432     Union All
    Select  25, 25      Union All
    Select  87, 87      Union All
    Select  100, 100 
)
Update  T
Set     Col1 = U.Col1,
        Col3 = U.Col1 + Col2
From    MyTable     T
Join    ToUpdate    U   On  U.Code = T.Code
```